# Is there a hotkey to go back from the search results view on Google calendar?

Tags: hotkeys, google-calendar

[image: is there a hotkey to go back from the search results?]

After doing a search in Google Calendar, is there a keyboard hotkey that is equivalent to clicking this back key (circled above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Rather unsurprisingly, it's **Esc**.

Comment: Welcome to superuser:  This provides an answer to the question and should be marked as such so that other users can find it. Superuser lets you answer and accept your own questions  Any extra detail is always good but sometimes it is just a button to push. You can take a couple of minutes and read(if needed):- [help] .Answering: [answer], again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut is the **same as the shortcut for going *backward***, i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will also work on systems that don't disable backspace-as-backward behavior